# Archiva: Ghost repositories - how to get rid of them ?

Tags: archiva

It appears that my archiva repository is showing jar files which correspond to artifacts which do not exist any longer.  How can i remove them ?

[image: How can we remove archiva repos from the user interface , when clearly they do not exist anywhere in the repo?]

Answer (score 0):

Should be fixed in last 1.4-M4 you can delete this un the ui.